# Linux: hrtimer_start in interrupt context

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver

Is [hrtimer_start](http://www.gnugeneration.com/books/linux/2.6.20/kernel-api/re52.html) safe to call in interrupt context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is. [Here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/drivers/staging/dream/gpio_input.c#L151) it's called from [GPIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPIO) IRQ handler.